# spaces getting kept after non matching group

Tags: r, regex

I have a string that is in the form:
`string <- "text1 text2(stuff)(blahh)  text3"`. `text2(stuff)` is always there but the other pieces may or may not. sometimes theres just a lot of space after `(blah)` and sometimes theres more text.

I am trying to get only whats in the second parenthesis, `blah` in this case. I have (with the help of people on this site) gotten to the point of having this regular expression:

```
gsub(".*text\\((.{5})\\)(?:\\((.{5})\\).*)?", "\\2", string)
```

which gives desired results if both `(stuff)` and `(blahh)` are present, but space and `text3` otherwise. This one

```
gsub(".*text2\\((.{5})\\)(?:\\((.{5})\\))?.*", "\\2", string)
```

gives nothing back if only `stuff` is present which is what I want but also gives nothing if both are present.

If anyone could help me figure out how to get only `blah` I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
string <- "text1 text2(stuff)(blahh)  text3"
sub(".*text2\\([^()]*\\)(?:\\(([^()]*)\\))?.*", "\\1", string, perl=TRUE)
# => blah
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/woON0Y/1) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/NQiszP).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0 or more chars  (other than line break chars) as many as possible
- `text2\\(` - literal `text2(` text
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `(?:\(([^()]*)\))?` - an optional non-capturing group:

  - `\(`  - a `(` char
  - `([^()]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern refers to the text captured with this group): zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars  (other than line break chars) as many as possible

Comment: Thanks much @WiktorStribizew I'm curious why the version i was trying didn't work. Do you think its because I didn't enable perl?

Comment: @HunterClark I think it is possible. PCRE regex engine is much more stable and predictable.